# Eclipse Default Font name

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts

What's the default font that Eclipse uses for Java code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default font Eclipse uses for (Java) code is Monospace.

Comment: In my version of Eclipse Photon with Dark theme `Consolas` is the right answer.

Answer (score 14):

The default font style eclipse is using is `Consolas` however `Courier New` is also a good option to go with.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on your Eclipse version, the font might differ. Go to Window-> Preferences->General->Appearance->Color and Fonts. Choose Basic->Text Font and you can hit the Edit button to change font type and font size. It will be used by several other properties below that default to this font.

Answer (score 0):

For the Code, we see It's Menlo with font size as 14

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).